# How to return out of a function correctly?

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, atom-editor

So I got my push notifications to work just fine. Big issue I have is ***users will receive their own push notifications*** if they like/comment on their own photo. I have NO idea how to solve this issue.  For example lets say I like my own photo, I get the push notification " Clint liked your post" Which is me, same with commenting, if I am responding to a comment on my post. " Clint commented on your post".

Here is the code I wrote via Atom for notifications.

```
exports.observeComments = functions.database.ref('/comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onCreate((snapshot, event) => {
     var postId = event.params.postId;
     var commentId = event.params.commentId;

     return admin.database().ref('/comments/' + postId + '/' + commentId).once('value', snapshot => {
       var comment = snapshot.val();
       var commentUid = comment.uid;

       return admin.database().ref('/users/' + commentUid).once('value', snapshot => {
         var commentingUser = snapshot.val();
         var username = commentingUser.username;

         return admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId).once('value', snapshot => {
           var post = snapshot.val();
           var postOwnerUid = post.ownerUid;

           return admin.database().ref('/users/' + postOwnerUid).once('value', snapshot => {
             var postOwner = snapshot.val();

             var payload = {
               notification: {
                 body: username + ' commented on your post '

               }
             };

             admin.messaging().sendToDevice(postOwner.fcmToken, payload)
             .then((response) => {
               // Response is a message ID string.
               console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
               return response;
             })
             .catch((error) => {
               console.log('Error sending message:', error);
               throw new Error('Error sending message:', error);
             });
           })
         })
       })
     })
   })


exports.observeLikes = functions.database.ref('/user-likes/{uid}/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, event) => {
     var uid = event.params.uid;
     var postId = event.params.postId;

     return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {
       var userThatLikedPost = snapshot.val();

       return admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId).once('value', snapshot => {
         var post = snapshot.val();

         return admin.database().ref('/users/' + post.ownerUid).once('value', snapshot => {
           var postOwner = snapshot.val();

           var payload = {
             notification: {
               body: userThatLikedPost.username + ' liked your post '
             }
           };

           admin.messaging().sendToDevice(postOwner.fcmToken, payload)
           .then((response) => {
             // Response is a message ID string.
             console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
             return response;
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error sending message:', error);
             throw new Error('Error sending message:', error);
           });
             });
         })
       })
     })
```

Comment: just for basic understanding, you need to exclude your logged in user device id from your business logic .

Comment: Would  do you happen to have an example or a source I can  reference to go off of ?

Comment: @iOSTeam sorry forgot to mention you..

Comment: have you done with you issue ?

Comment: @iOSTeam I'm sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: your above issue of push-notification has resolved ?

Comment: @iOSTeam  oh no, still having the issue. I was asking you if you didn't mind providing an example on how to exclude logging in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to add break condition.
Just add after

> var postOwnerUid = post.ownerUid;

this lines:

```js
if(commentUid === postOwnerUid)
  return Promise.resolve();
```

and after

> var post = snapshot.val();

this lines:

```js
if(uid === post.ownerUid)
  return Promise.resolve();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm not familiar with this language to much, when you say add a break condition do I need to add ```break;``` anywhere?

Comment: No, this is it. You don't need to add anything else. I meant "break" like expression rather then "break" explicitly.

Comment: Do you mind telling me if I did It correctly? I added it to the oberseveComments code.  However now I am not receiving any notifications for comments at all. I'll update my question and add the code now. @Maciej Fryta Frydrychowicz

Comment: Figured it out, I just wasn't defining the UID correctly. THANK YOU